# Single Line Linux Handler that Checks a Var and Directory Exists

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement

I'm wanting to create a one-liner in a Bash script to check if a string variable matches as well as a directory exists?

Currently have this, but it's failing:

```
DEBUG="TRUE"

[[ ${DEBUG} == "TRUE" && -d /debug ]] && cp /etc/apache2/httpd.conf /debug/httpd.BEFORE.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible way to write a single-line Linux command that checks if a variable and directory exist:

```
if [[ -n $VAR && -d $DIR ]]; then echo "Variable and directory exist"; fi
```

This command uses the `if` statement to check if the variable VAR is non-empty (`-n $VAR`) and if the directory DIR exists (`-d $DIR`). If both conditions are true, the command will print "Variable and directory exist".

Comment: What if `DEBUG="FALSE"` ? ;)